# How is this snake moving?

Tags: java

I am trying to understand a java game code but cant move past this problem.

This is a snake and apple game. I don't understand the few lines where I have commented out with "???". I dont understand how is this snake moving. I dont understand draw and move method, especially the move method.

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 600;
    static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    static final int UNIT_SIZE = 25;
    static final int GAME_UNITS = (SCREEN_WIDTH*SCREEN_HEIGHT)/(UNIT_SIZE*UNIT_SIZE);
    static final int DELAY = 75;
    final int x[] = new int[GAME_UNITS];
    final int y[] = new int[GAME_UNITS];
    int bodyParts = 6;
    int applesEaten;
    int appleX;
    int appleY;
    char direction = 'R';
    boolean running = false;
    Timer timer;
    Random random;
    

    public void draw (Graphics g) {
        for(int i=0; i<SCREEN_HEIGHT/UNIT_SIZE; i++) {
            g.drawLine(i*UNIT_SIZE, 0 , i*UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_HEIGHT);//x1,y1,x2,y2 ,basically first point and last point
            g.drawLine(0, i*UNIT_SIZE , SCREEN_WIDTH, i*UNIT_SIZE);
        }
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(appleX, appleY, UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE); 
    
        for (int i=0; i<bodyParts;i++) {//?????????????what does this mean ?
            if(i==0) {
                g.setColor(Color.green);
                g.fillRect(x[i],y[i], UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);//??
                
            }
            else {
                g.setColor(new Color(45,180,0));
                g.fillRect(x[i],y[i],UNIT_SIZE,UNIT_SIZE);
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    public void move () {
        for(int i = bodyParts;i>0;i--) {//?????????????what does this mean ?, why i--
            x[i] = x[i-1];///?????????????????????what does this mean ?
            y[i] = y[i-1];/////what does this mean ?
        }
        switch(direction) {
        case 'R':
            y[0] = y[0] + UNIT_SIZE; //????????????????what is this doing ???
            break;
        
    }
```

Comment: Why not ask the author? --- Please read: [How to debug small programs (`https://ericlippert.com/`)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Looks like you don't know basics of (Java) programming: loops, pre/post-incrementation, and array indexing?

Answer (score 0):

- Iterate through the integers from 0 to `bodyParts`
- Draw a square of size UNIT_SIZE*UNIT_SIZE at the coordinate `(x[i],y[i])`
- The head of the snake (first coordinate stored in x and y) is green, the rest of the body is light blue
- The snake moves by altering the position of its bodyparts one by one, setting the current element's position to that of the following element, this starts from the back to avoid having to create temporary variables
- After having altered the position of every bodyPart of the snake the head's position is altered as well, if `direction` equaled `'R'`, then the snake's head "goes down" by UNIT_SIZE. (it results in the snake's head going down because in Swing the top-left of the screen is the starting point, so the coordinate pair `(0,0)`, by adding to the head's height coordinate (y) you're moving it away from the top, which is down.